# Trying to use a $ value inside a path to move the files based on this php file

Tags: php

I am trying to get the file to upload an image or audio file to the following directory

`$dir='sites/default/documents/"$patientID"/'` but I don't know how to use the exact syntax with the `$` sign inside a path.

I used the get method to get the patientID from the controller but still nothing is working

Comment: If you're using Double quotes, you don't need to escape the variable. And even if you wanted to, you can concatenate with . $patientID .

Comment: `$dir='sites/default/documents/'.$patientID.'/'` try that

Comment: Concatenate string with `.` in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead : `$dir="sites/default/documents/$patientID/";`

In your case the variable is considered as a text.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes do not interpolate values, even if there are double quotes inside them. The initial string must be a double quote string, in order for any interpolation to occur inside of it.

If there's any doubt about the complexity of the variable name, use braces to encapsulate the interpolation. `$dir="sites/default/documents/{$patientID}/";`